# HTML input file won't open camera

Tags: android, html, image, input, camera

I'm developing an app to Android with Cordova, and in it i need to open the camera for a picture. The tag  should do it, but it is only opening the gallery. Here's what i've already tried:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture />
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" />
<input type="file" accept="image" capture="camera" />
```

Do not know if it's relevant, but my phone is a Moto X Play, with 6.0.1 Android.

None of these made it. Maybe I'm using it wrong. Hope you guys may help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for answering my question though. I've used an alternative solution based on this reading http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html which works very well and I didn't had to use input type file anymore.